# About the energy of electron (whether constant or variate)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics

According to Einstein E=mc^2.It means that the total energy of the electron is constant.But we also know that electrons undergo wave motion.As the electrons undergo wave motion the energy of the electron must increase and decrease with respect to crest and trough in the wave motion.This is contrast to einstein's energy.please explain.

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is  based around  mixing up lots of different concepts about the electron and wave-particle notions.  You need to read more about the subject on  Wikipedia and other sites,  about probability waves, photons and how they affect the energy that the electron possesses at any given time.

Comment: You are confusing a ***lot*** of conceptual stuff. First of all, $E = mc^2$ is the energy of particles at rest, i.e, whose momentum is zero. Secondly, electrons as particles, don't undergo wave motion. They themselves behave as waves. Thirdly, I can give you an idea about the energy of an electron in the sense of the Bohr model, not QM (I haven't learnt much of it yet), where the total energy $E = T + U = T - 2T (U  \propto  r^{-1}) = -T$, where $T$ and $U$ are the kinetic and potential energies of the electron respectively.

Comment: My apologies for misreading your question. As you have accepted John's correct answer, you can upvote it as well. This is just for any further questions you might ask, John is (deservedly) not low on reputation points:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation:

$$ E = mc^2 $$

is a special case of the more general equation:

$$ E^2 = p^2c^2 + m^2c^4 $$

where $p$ is the momentum of the particle. In the rest frame of the electron its momentum is zero and the more general equation reduces to the special case.

The wave motion you are describing is for an electron moving with some non-zero momentum. The de Broglie wavelength of the electron is related to its momentum by:

$$ \lambda = \frac{h}{p} $$

So you can write the expression for the energy using the wavelength instead of the momentum:

$$ E^2 = \frac{h^2c^2}{\lambda^2} + m^2c^4 $$

Answer (score 0):

A short answer. $E=Mc^2$ is called the rest energy of the electron and is the same value for all electrons, no matter how fast they move or in in what direction they move.

The electron does not move in waves. So it does not acquire or lose any energy by way of wave motion. It acquires extra momentum and kinetic energy it when absorbs a photon from, say another electron.

So if two electrons interact, one loses energy and the other one gains it, this is known as the conservation of energy and means the total amount of energy of the two particle system is constant.

You need to read up  whatever textbook you have, or search the web for explanations that you are happy with, and this will take a while to do.